# Resurrecting an Angular4 project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to resurrect an Angular 4 project I wrote in 2017.  My understanding is that to install angular 4 and the 1.4 cli I need to run npm install @angular/cli@1.4.  My question is which versions of node and npm do I need to install?  Installing the latest node/npm won't allow angular to install.  Is there a way I can tell which versions of node/npm were used in my original angular project?

Answer (score 0):

Installing node.js from https://nodejs.org/download/release/v6.11.0/node-v6.11.0-x64.msi (node 6.11.0 and npm 3.10.10) did the trick.

see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular4/angular4_project_setup.htm